# Modifying Rails helpers to add HTML classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-css-framework

I'm starting to use the [jQuery UI CSS Framework](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API) for an app, which means I have to start adding classes to everything. So, for example, I want to make all buttons jQuery-themed, which means adding a class to all buttons.

I imagine there's some way in Rails to modify the helpers so I don't have to manually add a `:class => 'blah'` to every button, but I can't work it out. Is this possible, or does anybody have any better ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need override  the helper method with this class add. In your application_helper.rb

```
  def button_to(name, options = {}, html_options = {})
    super(name, options, html_options.merge(:class => 'blah'))
  end
```

Comment: Is there a way you can specify more classes, apart from the default 'blah' class ? edit: I used `html_options.merge(:class => (html_options[:class] || '') + ' blah')` is that ok to use?

Comment: The problem is that both string and array is allowed for class

Answer (score 3):

Why not use jquery, somthing like:

```
$('button').attr('class', 'blah');
```

Comment: That's not a bad idea actually. There must be a simple way to do this in Rails though, surely.

Comment: I've done some more reading and it looks like this may be the most sensible answer - it doesn't look like a simple task to override helper methods. I'll mark this accepted unless I get a Rails-based solution today.

Comment: I actually went this route in the end - the helper way had too many edge cases, and I'm not writing all my HTML with helpers anyway. The jQuery way keeps it all in one place with one technique. I don't really feel like I can mark this as the accepted answer though, because the other one answers the question I actually asked. But thanks anyway!